# Return list element's pointer if has the same name

Tags: c++, list

I have a method that checks if there is an element in a list with the same name as the parameter.  If it's found, I want to return a pointer to it, and if the method does not find anything, then return a null pointer.  Here's the function:

```
Place *PlacesMap::Check(string name) {
    for (list<Place>::iterator iterator = map.begin(); iterator != map.end(); iterator++) {
        Place current = *iterator;
        if (current.GetName() == name)
            return &*iterator;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

A Place has a Name and Info, both strings, that is the class:

```
class Place {

private:
    string name;
    string info;

public:
    Place();
    Place(string name, string info);

    inline string GetName() {
        return name;
    }

    inline string GetInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    inline void Set(string newName, string newInfo) {
        name = newName;
        info = newInfo;
    }
};
```

When I insert another Place in the list of Places, if there is already an element with the same name, it only updates the info. To do that, I iterate through the list, and check if there is already a Place with that name, and if there is I update the info, that is working fine. But the when I try to insert a Place that already exist, it updates the info, and after checking it with the Check method, it still shows the old info. What I'm doing wrong on the Check method?

This is the implementation of the insert method:

```
void PlacesMap::Insert(Place p) {
    if (!map.empty()) {
        for (list<Place>::iterator iterator = map.begin(); iterator != map.end(); iterator++) {
            Place current = *iterator;
            if (current.GetName() == p.GetName())  {
                current.Set(p.GetName(), p.GetInfo());
            } else if ((iterator == --map.end())) {
                map.insert(iterator, p);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        map.insert(map.end(), p);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, also provide your Insert method.

Comment: change `return &*iterator;` to `return iterator;` or `return &current`

Comment: If I use return &current it gives me a warning: Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'current' returned.

Comment: @Minato, either of those changes would be wrong.  `&*iterator` is generally correct for that kind of situation.

Comment: `Place current = *iterator;` should have been `Place& current = *iterator;` in both points in the code where that line was.  In `PlacesMap::Check` that is a style/efficiency issue (and the reason `return &current` won't work).  In `Insert` that is not just style/efficiency.  It is a bug.

Comment: You're returning/passing far too many things by value which you should be returning/passing by reference.

Comment: @zenith, I assume you mean return/pass by const reference, not pass by reference.  It wouldn't make a difference in this trivial code, but the difference is important in real projects.

Comment: Of course. Always const by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is you try to get the copy of element in line:

```
Place current = *iterator;
```

in your Insert method code. You need to use reference instead. Please, try:

```
Place &current = *iterator;
```

Answer (score 3):

This part of the `Insert` function

```
Place current = *iterator;
if (current.GetName() == p.GetName())  {
    current.Set(p.GetName(), p.GetInfo());
```

creates a **copy** of the node as `current`, and then updates the copy. It should probably do

```
iterator->Set(p.GetName(), p.GetInfo());
```

BTW, using the variable name `iterator` for an object of type `iterator`, isn't the best idea. I hesitated quite a bit before writing this line of code.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep in mind that naming thing for iterators.